# On the meaning of $\mathbb{R_+}$

Tags: notation

$\mathbb{R_+}=[0,+\infty]$ or $\mathbb{R_+}=[0,+\infty)$?

Thanks!

Comment: See [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $\infty$ is *not* a real number, $\Bbb R_+=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid x>0\}=(0,{+}\infty)$.

In some places, however, $0$ might be included (if my memory serves me right the French system is to include $0$ in the term "positive"), in which case this is $[0,{+}\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

If not specified $\mathbb{R_+}$ means $(0, \infty)$. We generally don't include $\infty$ in this case and also $0$.